# Using Include from 3 tables LINQ .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, linq

I've been figuring out how to create a query using LINQ (I am a total newb).

My goal is to create a table that will use query out from these 3 models and filter them based from **OrderDate** in **CustomerOrder** Model:

```
class Item
        [Key]
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal ItemCost { get; set; }
        public string ItemImage { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ItemsInOrder> ItemsInOrders { get; set; }

class ItemsInOrder
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }

        public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerOrder CustomerOrderNavigation { get; set; }

class CustomerOrder
        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ItemsInOrder> ItemsInOrders { get; set; }
```

```
            var testQuery = _context.Items
                .Include(o=>o.ItemsInOrders)
                .ThenInclude(i=>i.OrderNumberNavigation);
```

the query above doesn't give me access to the attributes of other tables aside from Items.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by using conditional statement.

```
var testQuery = _context.Items.Select(i => i);

if(yearParameter != 0)
{
testQuery = testQuery
                    .Include(o => o.ItemsInOrders)
                    .Where(x => x.ItemsInOrders.Any(x => x.CustomerOrderNavigation.OrderDate.Year == yearParameter));
}
```

pretty sure this can still be optimised but as long as it works i'll take it.

PS: (please excuse the name convention of my lambda expressions, it's just for Q & A purpose only)